# Extend WP_Customize_Control with Multiple Field Control

Tags: custom-field, theme-customizer, customization, settings-api

I'm trying to figure out how to code a custom control but frustratingly all the information I find online points to the same example of creating a single textfield.

I'd like to create a custom control which presents 4 input fields for padding (top,right,bottom,left)

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <th>Top</th>
        <th>Right</th>
        <th>Bottom</th>
        <th>Left</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="number" name="top" min="0" max="20"></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="right" min="0" max="20"></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="bottom" min="0" max="20"></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="left" min="0" max="20"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve my goal not by creating a custom control with multiple input fields but by creating creating a custom control which still accepted a single input, but would display inline with other controls.

Here's the custom control for an inline numerical input:

```
class Customizer_Number_Inline_Control extends WP_Customize_Control {
    public $fieldwidth = 'text';
    public $type = 'number';

    protected function render() {
        $id = 'customize-control-' . str_replace( '[', '-', str_replace( ']', '', $this->id ) );
        $class = 'customize-control customize-control-' . $this->type; ?>
        <li id="<?php echo esc_attr( $id ); ?>" class="<?php echo esc_attr( $class ); ?>" style="clear:none;display:inline-block;max-width:<?php echo $this->fieldwidth . "%"; ?>">
            <?php $this->render_content(); ?>
        </li>
    <?php }

    public function render_content() { ?>
        <label class="inline">
            <span class="customize-control-title" style="font-size:10px;line-height:10px;height:20px;"><?php echo esc_html( $this->label ); ?></span>
            <input type="number" <?php $this->link(); ?> value="<?php echo intval( $this->value() ); ?>" />
        </label>
    <?php }
}
```

---

I added an additional parameter to set the width of the control so if you want to have three controls inline you set each of them to 33 (33%), if you want 2 you set each of them to 50%.. etc..

Implementing this into a setting looks something like this.

```
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'width', array (
    'default'   => '77',
    'type'      => 'option',
) );
$wp_customize->add_control( new Customizer_Number_Inline_Control( $wp_customize, 'width', array (
    'label'     => 'Width',
    'type'      => 'number',
    'section'   => 'site',
    'priority'  => 1,
    'fieldwidth'=> '50', //set the field to 50% width so that we can display a second one next to it
) ) );
```